# How to get a gold laurel wreath at Arlon's Lunar Sanctum?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I have played this level multiple times, and I cannot seem to find everything in that level. Could someone point out where all of the treasure boxes and intensity gates(If there is any for this level) are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In the first mirrored room, the false wall on the left has a chest behind it. (May require 5.0+ - sometimes I've had it only spit out hearts.)
- Rather than go in the door after the bridge where Palutena sneezes, go around behind it to find a chest.
- There's a chest on a platform only reachable by an Exo Tank jump, in the outside area. You do not need to boost to make the jump.
- You need to take out the enemies on the spinning platform near the end of the level to make another chest appear.
- Right before the boss, turn left to find a level 7 intensity gate.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed that intensity gate. thanks!

Comment: There is also a secret area where you go down the river of sand near the beginning of the stage. If you look carefully there's a holographic wall on your right near the first bend. Inside is a treasure box.